# PHP not rendering html

Tags: php, html

I am writing an image management script in php. All of the php code regarding the image management works just fine. The problem is the script fails to render the small amount of html at the top which includes an animated loading gif.

Depending on the number of images being managed, it can take some time so I would like the html at the top to render. I have tried to place it in a function and call the function after the html but the script goes right to the image processing.

This page is being called into an Iframe from another page in the Iframe.

```
<?php
    $level = '../../';

    include('class.upload.php');    
    $folder = $_REQUEST['folder'];  

# render success page
    echo '<html><body>';
    echo '<h3 style="color: red">Processing...</h3>';
    echo 'This might take awhile... Your patience is much appreciated.';
    echo '<br><br><br><div style="text-align: center"><img src="ajaxloader.gif"></div>';
    echo '</body></html>';  


    $icon = $_REQUEST['icon'];
    $thumb = $_REQUEST['thumb'];
    $small = $_REQUEST['small'];
    $medium = $_REQUEST['medium'];
    $large = $_REQUEST['large'];
    $xlarge = $_REQUEST['xlarge'];

    foreach(glob('images/temp/*') as $image) {
    if($icon >= 1){copy($image, 'images/100/' . basename($image));}
    if($thumb >= 1){copy($image, 'images/150/' . basename($image));}
    if($small >= 1){copy($image, 'images/320/' . basename($image));}
    if($medium >= 1){copy($image, 'images/640/' . basename($image));}
    if($large >= 1){copy($image, 'images/960/' . basename($image));}
    if($xlarge >= 1){copy($image, 'images/1280/' . basename($image));}
    }



# xlarge folder     
    $startdir= 'images/1280/';
$dir="$startdir$subdir";$array_dir=array();$array_file=array();if(is_dir($dir)){if($dh=opendir($dir)){while(($file=readdir($dh))!==false){$filename=$file;$filetype=filetype($dir.$file);if($filename==".."OR$filename=="."){echo"";}else{if($filetype=="file"){$array_file[]=$filename;}elseif($filetype=="dir"){$array_dir[]=$filename;}}}closedir($dh);}}sort($array_dir);   

    foreach ($array_file as $image_file){   
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($startdir.$image_file);
        if($width >= 1280){
            $handle = new upload($startdir.$image_file);
            if ($handle->uploaded) {
                $handle->file_name_body_add   = '_large';
                $handle->image_resize         = true;
                $handle->image_x              = 1280;
                $handle->image_ratio_y        = true;
                $handle->process($folder.'/1280/');
                if ($handle->processed) {$handle->clean();} 
                else {echo 'error : ' . $handle->error;}
            }
        }        
    }

# large folder      
    $startdir= 'images/960/';
$dir="$startdir$subdir";$array_dir=array();$array_file=array();if(is_dir($dir)){if($dh=opendir($dir)){while(($file=readdir($dh))!==false){$filename=$file;$filetype=filetype($dir.$file);if($filename==".."OR$filename=="."){echo"";}else{if($filetype=="file"){$array_file[]=$filename;}elseif($filetype=="dir"){$array_dir[]=$filename;}}}closedir($dh);}}sort($array_dir);   

    foreach ($array_file as $image_file){   
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($startdir.$image_file);
        if($width >= 960){
            $handle = new upload($startdir.$image_file);
            if ($handle->uploaded) {
                $handle->file_name_body_add   = '_large';
                $handle->image_resize         = true;
                $handle->image_x              = 960;
                $handle->image_ratio_y        = true;
                $handle->process($folder.'/960/');
                if ($handle->processed) {$handle->clean();} 
                else {echo 'error : ' . $handle->error;}
            }
        }        
    }

# medium folder     
    $startdir= 'images/640/';
$dir="$startdir$subdir";$array_dir=array();$array_file=array();if(is_dir($dir)){if($dh=opendir($dir)){while(($file=readdir($dh))!==false){$filename=$file;$filetype=filetype($dir.$file);if($filename==".."OR$filename=="."){echo"";}else{if($filetype=="file"){$array_file[]=$filename;}elseif($filetype=="dir"){$array_dir[]=$filename;}}}closedir($dh);}}sort($array_dir);   

    foreach ($array_file as $image_file){   
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($startdir.$image_file);
        if($width >= 640){
            $handle = new upload($startdir.$image_file);
            if ($handle->uploaded) {
                $handle->file_name_body_add   = '_large';
                $handle->image_resize         = true;
                $handle->image_x              = 640;
                $handle->image_ratio_y        = true;
                $handle->process($folder.'/640/');
                if ($handle->processed) {$handle->clean();} 
                else {echo 'error : ' . $handle->error;}
            }
        }        
    }

# small folder      
    $startdir= 'images/320/';
$dir="$startdir$subdir";$array_dir=array();$array_file=array();if(is_dir($dir)){if($dh=opendir($dir)){while(($file=readdir($dh))!==false){$filename=$file;$filetype=filetype($dir.$file);if($filename==".."OR$filename=="."){echo"";}else{if($filetype=="file"){$array_file[]=$filename;}elseif($filetype=="dir"){$array_dir[]=$filename;}}}closedir($dh);}}sort($array_dir);   

    foreach ($array_file as $image_file){   
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($startdir.$image_file);
        if($width >= 320){
            $handle = new upload($startdir.$image_file);
            if ($handle->uploaded) {
                $handle->file_name_body_add   = '_large';
                $handle->image_resize         = true;
                $handle->image_x              = 320;
                $handle->image_ratio_y        = true;
                $handle->process($folder.'/320/');
                if ($handle->processed) {$handle->clean();} 
                else {echo 'error : ' . $handle->error;}
            }
        }        
    }

# thumb folder      
    $startdir= 'images/150/';
$dir="$startdir$subdir";$array_dir=array();$array_file=array();if(is_dir($dir)){if($dh=opendir($dir)){while(($file=readdir($dh))!==false){$filename=$file;$filetype=filetype($dir.$file);if($filename==".."OR$filename=="."){echo"";}else{if($filetype=="file"){$array_file[]=$filename;}elseif($filetype=="dir"){$array_dir[]=$filename;}}}closedir($dh);}}sort($array_dir);   

    foreach ($array_file as $image_file){   
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($startdir.$image_file);
        if($width >= 150){
            $handle = new upload($startdir.$image_file);
            if ($handle->uploaded) {
                $handle->file_name_body_add   = '_large';
                $handle->image_resize         = true;
                $handle->image_x              = 150;
                $handle->image_ratio_y        = true;
                $handle->process($folder.'/150/');
                if ($handle->processed) {$handle->clean();} 
                else {echo 'error : ' . $handle->error;}
            }
        }        
    }

# icon folder       
    $startdir= 'images/100/';
$dir="$startdir$subdir";$array_dir=array();$array_file=array();if(is_dir($dir)){if($dh=opendir($dir)){while(($file=readdir($dh))!==false){$filename=$file;$filetype=filetype($dir.$file);if($filename==".."OR$filename=="."){echo"";}else{if($filetype=="file"){$array_file[]=$filename;}elseif($filetype=="dir"){$array_dir[]=$filename;}}}closedir($dh);}}sort($array_dir);   

    foreach ($array_file as $image_file){   
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($startdir.$image_file);
        if($width >= 100){
            $handle = new upload($startdir.$image_file);
            if ($handle->uploaded) {
                $handle->file_name_body_add   = '_large';
                $handle->image_resize         = true;
                $handle->image_x              = 100;
                $handle->image_ratio_y        = true;
                $handle->process($folder.'/100/');
                if ($handle->processed) {$handle->clean();} 
                else {echo 'error : ' . $handle->error;}
            }
        }        
    }   
# unlink temp folder images
    $startdir= 'images/temp/';
$dir="$startdir$subdir";$array_dir=array();$array_file=array();if(is_dir($dir)){if($dh=opendir($dir)){while(($file=readdir($dh))!==false){$filename=$file;$filetype=filetype($dir.$file);if($filename==".."OR$filename=="."){echo"";}else{if($filetype=="file"){$array_file[]=$filename;}elseif($filetype=="dir"){$array_dir[]=$filename;}}}closedir($dh);}}sort($array_dir);   

    foreach ($array_file as $image_file){unlink($startdir.$image_file);}

    echo '<Script language="javascript">window.location="success.php"</script>';
?
```

>

Any assistance is much appreciated,
Pete

Comment: probably need a few `flush()` calls sprinkled in there, to try and force sending any html sitting in the output queue. And PHP doesn't "render" html. That's the browser's job. PHP simply GENERATES the html. But if that html never gets sent out to the client, then obviously the client won't have anything to render.

Comment: Look at http://php.net/flush - though note that there are certain cases where it does nothing (e.g. when PHP is run as a CGI script).

Comment: I read the php.net flush docs and tried placing the flush and tried placing the flush function just before the closing bracket of each of the foreach ($array_file as $image_file){. didn't work... not quite sure where they should go and if an ob_flush would be needed... thanks for the advice

Comment: Put your image processing code in a function so that you don't have to repeat the same hunk six times.